# Python: How to check if element of string is in a string and print the not included string elements?

Tags: python, list

I want to check each list element of c in alphabet and print the letters of the alphabet, which are not in a list element of c.

For example, shall the first list element of c "aa" print all letters of alphabet in a string excluding the letter a.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   
c = ['aa', 'bb', 'zz']

for x in c:
  if x in alphabet:
    print(alphabet)
  else:
    print('not an element of alphabet')
```

Comment: you're missing the expected output...

Comment: Do you mean for for `aa` it should print `bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and for `bb` the string `acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`?

Comment: Yes. Code Pope got the intention of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```py
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   
cases = ['aa', 'bb', 'zz']

for case in cases:
    missing_letters = []
    for letter in alphabet:
        if letter not in case:
            missing_letters.append(letter)
    print(f"Case {case} misses following alphabeth letters {missing_letters}")
```

Output:

```
Case aa misses following alphabeth letters ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the elements in `c` are all in the format of `'xx'` like in your sample, then the following is a solution:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   
c = ['ad', 'bb', 'zz','ad', 'bt', 'uz']

for x in c:
  new_alph = alphabet
  for char in x:
    new_alph = new_alph.replace(char,'')
  if new_alph == alphabet:
    print('not an element of alphabet')
  else:
    print(new_alph)
```

Output:

```
bcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
bcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
acdefghijklmnopqrsuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxy
```

Another way is to use `translate` to make the code more compact:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   
c = ['ad', 'bb', 'zz','ad', 'bt', 'uz']

for x in c:
  new_alph = alphabet.translate({ord(char): '' for char in x})
  if new_alph == alphabet:
    print('not an element of alphabet')
  else:
    print(new_alph)
```

Output:

```
bcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
bcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
acdefghijklmnopqrsuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxy
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks! and if I have two different letters in one list element: c = ['ad', 'bt', 'uz']

Comment: @StephanLeinert Ok, now I understand your goal. I have updated the code. You will get the desired result. The solution will work for any length the elements in `c` have.

Comment: @StephanLeinert I have also added another more compact way to do the job. See the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the strings in c are only 2 chars this will work

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   
c = ['aa', 'bb', 'zz']

for x in c:
  if x[0] in alphabet or x[1] in alphabet:
    alphabet.replace(x[0], '').replace(x[1], '')
  else:
    print('not an element of alphabet')
```